# Huawei Auth service code: 490 cse internal bad request

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I am using huawei auth service in my app. Sometimes, when the user is logging in with the huawei id, I get the code: 490 cse internal bad request error. What is the cause of this error?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQuBh.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

If 490 is returned, it is caused by a network error. Please try to connect again.

I have contacted with Auth Service Team, and this issue will be optimized timely.